# the problem is abt functions in javascript

Tags: javascript, function

this is the javascript code its making an error. at point of functions and I need to print the values of evens and unfortunately the code I made mistake and I cant able to figure it out whats the mistake is can I get some suggestions on the code so I can improve

```js
function displayEvenNumbers(){
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var evenNumbers = [];
    for(var i=0; i<numbers.length-1; i++;){
        if(numbers % 2 = 0); {
            evenNumbers.push(i);
        }
        return evenNumbers;
    }
}
displayEvenNumbers(); // should return [2,4,6,8]
```

Comment: Extra semicolon here `if(numbers % 2 = 0);` and here `i++;`, get rid of those. And `(numbers % 2 = 0)` should be `(numbers % 2 === 0)`.

Comment: To resolve problems like this use a [JavaScript validator](http://beautifytools.com/javascript-validator.php), or better yet a linter like [ESLint](https://eslint.org/)

Comment: AND you're **setting** `numbers = 2` --  You need a *comparison check* with double or triple `==`, `===` IE `numbers % 2 == 0`

Comment: Assuming you want the value of the array and not its position use `numbers[i]` in the if statement and push

Comment: Also, the `return` statement has to go outside of the `for loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code, check fixed one below and compare with yours

1. for(var i=0; i<numbers.length-1; i++`;` <-- You don't need this semicolon
2. if(numbers % 2 `=` 0) <-- Here you compare equality, so use `===` or `==`
3. You returning `return evenNumbers;` after first cycle of loop. You need to move it up from `for(){ ... }` scope

```js
function displayEvenNumbers(){
    var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
    var evenNumbers = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if(numbers[i] % 2 === 0) {
          evenNumbers.push(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
    return evenNumbers;
}
console.log(displayEvenNumbers()); // should return [2,4,6,8]
```